# Why is Pandas plotting index values (x_ticklabels) incorrectly?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I've got this data frame

```
                        Poverty      White      Black  Native_American
CHSI_State_Name                                                          
Alabama               17.085075  69.795522  28.510448         0.570149   
Alaska                12.144444  54.485185   1.174074        36.159259   
Arizona               16.840000  81.086667   1.886667        14.813333   
...
```

And I plot my figure like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
poverty.plot(ax = ax, figsize = (16, 8))
ax.set_xticklabels(poverty.index, rotation = 90)

fig.savefig('output7.png', xbbox_inches = 'tight')
```

I would expect the file to have state names under each value (all states), but instead it's only got a few with large gaps.[image: Output graph]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that

```
ax.set_xticklabels(poverty.index, rotation = 90)
```

sets the `xticklabels` on the range of the data. If your data ranges from 10 to 16, it will put names on 10,11,12,13,14 and 15.
Instead of putting labels on each integer `xtick` you want to specify the position / order of the labels as well.

By using

```
ax.set_xticks(range(len(poverty.index)))
```

You specify the range as big as the `poverty.index` which makes sure that each label is positioned inside your plot.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
ax.set_xticklabels(poverty.index, rotation = 90)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(poverty.index)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substitute `ax.set_xticklabels(poverty.index, rotation = 90)` with:

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)
```

For me it works with the expected behaviour. But actually I don't know how your method does not work. This is a proposal workaround. Hope that helps.

Comment: Better, but not quite. This works for some reason:

    ax.set_xticklabels(poverty.index, rotation = 90)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(poverty.index)))